# change a image height by jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change image height by jquery/javascript 
I dont want to set id for the image .

```
        <div class="list_carousel">
            <ul id="foo1">
                <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slider/1.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slider/2.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slider/3.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slider/4.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slider/5.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slider/6.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slider/7.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slider/8.jpg" alt="" /></li>
                <li><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/slider/9.jpg" alt="" /></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

In CSS

```
   .list_carousel img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   }
```

Comment: you want change all images size in the same time ?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/height

Comment: All of the images? Or just one? If all, what does it have to do with IDs? You mean class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select all the images with:

```
$('#foo1 img')
```

Or:

```
$('#foo1').find('img')
```

Therefore, you can change the height to 100% with:

```
$('#foo1').find('img').css({ height: '100%' });
```

Or if you want to change the height to a number of pixels (for example, 60):

```
$('#foo1').find('img').height(60);
```

---

If you want to change just one image, you can use:

```
$('#foo1').find('img').eq(index).height(60);
```

where `index` is the zero-based index of the image.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, you could use `getElementsByTagName` and change the height of one:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

x[2].childNodes[0].style.height = '100%';
```

That will change the image in the third `li` tag to 100% in height.

I didn't understand if you wanted all images changed, but if you did, you could use a `for loop`:

```
var x = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
{
    x[i].childNodes[0].style.height = '100%';
}
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/28L4R/2/

Comment: @user3072874  Did you want to change *all* images or *one?*